# Which unique (blue) guns are you able to get as a drop?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've recently started another playthrough in BL: TPS and was wondering: which unique guns are you able to farm?

I know of a few like the "Boomacorn" and "The Machine" are able to be dropped by the Sentinel and his Raid Boss variant.

Though mostly I am wondering about the special ***guns you start with, if you have saves of the other games***.

They are called "Bullpup" and "Smasher". So, can you farm these guns to get them on a higher level or will you only ever be able to use them the first few levels?

*P.S: If you know of a extensive list of which uniques can be dropped and which can't, I definitely wouldn't mind that.*

Comment: Here is a complete list, you'll want to scroll down a bit: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Unique

Comment: @Ryan Oh well, must've missed that. I always searched for the specific uniques. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There apparently [use to be an exploit](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/bullpup-loyalty-reward-farming-is-gone/361475) to farm the Bullpup, but it has been removed from the game.  Additionally, [the Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bullpup) says its obtained as a loyalty reward:

> The Bullpup is a unique shotgun manufactured by Hyperion. It is obtained as a loyalty reward for having a Borderlands save file present on one's hard drive.

The article does not mention it can be dropped, and based off the first link, it doesn't seem like it was ever able to be dropped so players used an exploit instead.

The same goes for the Smasher as [the Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Smasher) also states its a loyalty reward:

> The Smasher is a unique pistol manufactured by Jakobs. It is awarded as a loyalty reward to players who have save data from Borderlands 2.

I'm not sure if the same exploit for the Bullpup could be used to farm more Smashers, but it doesn't matter at this point anyway since it has been removed.

As Ryan said in the comments, [here is a list of the uniques](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Unique#Names_and_Locations_.28Borderlands:_The_Pre-Sequel.29) in the Pre Sequel (as well as the other games). Additionally, that list says for the Bullpup and Smasher that the Drop/Reward location is a loyalty reward also.

Comment: At least there is still the Maggie. So I don't necessarily need the Smasher. But good to know, nontheless. Thanks!